# Doctrine Query <timestamp

Tags: sql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have a colum "datetime", like this: `2012-06-04 15:40:20`.

I want to create a query in Doctrine that I get the data of previous time. Less than `2012-06-04 15:40:20`. How can I realize that in Doctrine.

Sorry, I just have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe the syntax is just:

```
$datetime = // your timestamp

->where('t.somefield < ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datetime))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Doctrine, but here is standard SQL to do what you want:

```
select *
from t
where t.datetime in (select max(datetime)
                     from t
                     where datetime < '2012-06-04 15:40:20'
                    )
```

If Doctrine supports standard SQL syntax, then something like this would work (you might have to input the date/time constant in a different way).